# UIWebView With Django

Tags: ios, swift, django, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that simply displays a website with the following code:

```
    let str8REDURL = URL(string: "https://str8red.com/")
    let str8REDURLRequest = URLRequest(url: str8REDURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(str8REDURLRequest)
```

The page is driven by Django on the backend that handles login authentication.  Is it possible to retrieve the django user id from and display it as a message within the app?

I know within the HTML i can just use `{{ user.id }}`.

If the user is not logged in the message could just say "Not Logged In".

I am using Swift 3.  Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django can generate the page with the data you need and store it in a JS variable:

```
<script>myData = {{ user.id }}</script>
```

Then you can access this something like that:

```
let myData = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(fromString: "myData")
```

Comment: Many thanks, I assume I would pop this in the webViewDidFinishLoad section?

Comment: @AlanTingey Yes.

Comment: I have added a different question about the webview here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190498/webviewdidfinishload-not-working

Comment: @AlanTingey Let me if you have issues. Also, you should consider switching to WKWebView. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but if I do let myData = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(fromString: "document.title")  I get a sensible response.  If I try it with "myData" it does not.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's not there. I suggest you open the web page with a desktop Chrome browser and try to get the `myData` JS variable in the developer console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145160/discussion-between-alan-tingey-and-thedp).